# Passing function to pyswarm

Tags: function

I wonder how can I pass the variables that I got from f3() function without calling it several time in Pyswarm. Basically, I need to call f3() in the objective function to get the slope and I have to call it again in constraint function to get the min_s.

```
from pyswarm import pso
def f1(b):
    # replace the new value of b
def f2(t, s):
    slope = s[10]-s[0]/t[10]-t[0]
    min_s = min(s[])
    return slope, min_s
def f3(B):
    t = []
    s = []
    f1(B)       
    Slope, Min_S = f2(t, s) 
    return slope, Min_S 
# ------------------- pyswarm ----------------------
def objective_function(x):
    B = x
    slope, min = F3(B)      # call f3()
    return slope
def con(x):
    B = x
    Slope, Min_S = f2(t, s) # call f3() again !!!!!
    return Min_S
lb = [-3, -1]
ub = [2, 6]
xopt, fopt = pso(objective_function, lb, ub, f_ieqcons=con)
```

Answer (score 0):

i guess the problem is that you didn't define your variables , it should be in the form of x[1], x[2] , etc.
check the documentaiton on this link
https://pyswarms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/usecases/train_neural_network.html#Constructing-a-custom-objective-function
and this link
https://pythonhosted.org/pyswarm/